# A distributed file storage for blob data

Tags: hdfs, distributed-computing

I wanted to use HDFS to store images/files. But I read online, about the drawbacks of HDFS due to the single namenode. I came across this framework called Cassandra which is a nosql distributed database, but once again it does not perform well for blob storage. Any suggestions on what to do for this problem i.e. a distributed file storage for blob data?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of HDFS coming (in beta) which solves the problem of single point failure of name node. Look at HDFS Federation and Namenode High Availability in CHD 4. You can find more information about them on cloudera website.

Comment: so they way I think of this problem is I have a simple RESTful API in python/node which puts stuff into the HDFS cluster and also retrieves it. Am I correct or you have a better architecture for implementing this?

Comment: I am not sure about your exact use case but as far as I know  RESTful API is possible. See here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html